# Why Heating of certain salts like Lead salts produce crackling sound?

Tags: salt

I recently discovered that heating of certain salts produces crackling sound and that is called Decrepitation. But I couldn’t figure out the reason why that happens moreover I couldn’t find anything satisfactory on the internet.

Comment: Are they hydrated?

Comment: One cause is water.

Comment: I read about lead nitrate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frankly speaking, you're reading too much into this phenomenon. Have you ever heard the satisfying crackling noise when you burn logs of wood in a bonfire? I'm sure you must've got the answer by now:
**Decrepitation is more of a physical process rather than a chemical process**.

When we write chemical equations, we treat compounds as single molecules, but in reality this is not so.
You specifically mentioned lead nitrate. You must be aware that it is a  white/colorless crystalline salt. To expound further,  [solid lead(II) nitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II)_nitrate#:%7E:text=The%20crystal%20structure%20of%20solid,cube%20with%20length%20784%20picometres.) exists in a [face centered cubic structure](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/matse81/node/2133). Coming back to your question, when we heat Pb(NO3)2, we don't heat a single molecule, we heat a *sample* of the salt.
When we do so, the crystal structure breaks as the entropy increases. The deformation of the crystalline structure causes sound energy to be evolved.

TL;DR: Breaking down of large crystals into smaller crystals and/or intermediates causes the crackling sound known as decrepitation.